# .pyc files don't get updated (only in Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, pyc

I am running into a problem where any changes I make to my .py Django files don't change the .pyc file, so the Django web site doesn't change until I manually delete the .pyc file.

This only happens when running a Django app/py files dependent on Django.

Example:

models.py: contains methods to update database

cron.py: Independent script that sets up Django environment and then uses models.py to update database as a cron job

For some reason, changes in cron.py are reflected when I run it with `python cron.py` but cron.py will NOT pick up any changes I make to models.py. It will run off of the old .pyc file which is consistent with that happens when I use models.py through the web app.

I've tried chmod 777 on the entire directory. Does anyone have any idea what is causing this? Is there any relevant code I can post?

Comment: don't chmod 777. in any case, is that in production with fastcgi?

Comment: @EduardGamonal

Production with regular wsgi. The settings are pretty much exactly like the djangoproject tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are running this your Django instance with apache, you will need to restart apache in order for the changes to reflect, which you can simply do using

```
sudo service apache2 graceful
```

The pyc files are autoupdated locally with the default django development server only.